# Visual Studio error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I'm getting the following error in Visual Studio 2008:

> Unable to create the component used to
>   generate ASP.NET Intellisense
>   information.  This can occur if Visual
>   Studio or the .NET Framework is not
>   installed correctly.

I've re-installed all versions of the .Net framework, run `devenv /resetuserdata` like suggested online, and did a repair install of Visual Studio. However, I still get the same error.

I can click past this message, but get subsequent errors about package loading errors.  Then the project won't build when it build just fine days ago.  Does anyone know how to correct this?

Comment: is this error shown on start-up? And the usual questions: Did you make sure to install Visual Studio with administrative privileges? Did you install something new on your machine around the time when that error first appeared?

Comment: @Stakx- Yes, error is at when I load a project into Visual Studio.  I am a local admin of this machine, so install should have been with admin priveledges (1+ year ago).  I didn't install anything like a Visual Studio Add-in recentlly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

about 4-5 months before i was also getting this error, but i resolved that by unistalling each and every component of Visual studio and Sql server and then again installing it....

I still don't know y this error had come.